# How do I create a SharePoint 2010 wsp and include a webpart already built as a DLL and strong signed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, wsp

I have a SharePoint 2010 Visual WebPart that is built with MSBuild (ILMerged with dependencies) and strong signed - A.dll

Separately I have a SharePoint project B that I want to use to package all my WebParts and create a B.wsp

How do I include WebPart A.dll in the feature of project B and subsequently the package so it is included and available in the resultant B.wsp?

Thanks, Confused

Comment: Additionally I'd like to also package the mapped folders for images and js files from Project A.

Answer (score 1):

To add a DLL to a SharePoint Solution Package using Visual Studio 2010:

- open Package from the Solution Explorer
- click the Advanced tab
- under Additional Assemblies, click Add > Add Existing Assembly...
- locate your DLL and click OK

Note that if the WebPart A project is part of your Visual Studio solution along with SharePoint Project B, then you can use Add Assembly from Project Output instead of Add Existing Assembly. Then any changes you make to the WebPart A project will be included the next time you package Project B.